# How to use printf in bash to print on screen and output into a variable

Tags: bash, printf

How can I `printf "abc"` in bash and at the same time append a variable with the text from printf?

Comment: it's not clear (to me) what you're asking for; can you update the question with an example of what the variable contains and the expected output/result?

Comment: `var=$var$(printf "moo" | tee /dev/stderr)` would do roughly what you ask, but pollute standard error. The blindingly obvious solution `printf -v bar "moo"; printf '%s\n' "$bar"; var=$var$bar` is perhaps not so elegant, but probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee that's what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in one go, but you can output the variable once it contains the output.

```sh
text=$(printf abc)
printf '%s' "$text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or @choroba' example conditionally...

```
text=$(printf abc) && printf '%s' "$text" || printf "FAIL!\n"
```

Thats a shorthand for: `if [ command ]; (&&) then command; (||) else command; fi`

Answer (score 0):

Or, using `-v`:

```
printf -v text abc
printf '%s' "$text"
```